# How to solve divs overlapping issue and maintain css fluid layout?

Tags: css

I have two divs left and right, when I restore down (minimize window) the right div comes on top of the left div (overlapping in other words).

How do I solve this problem?

```
#left {
    left: 3%;   
    position: absolute;
    width: 340px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#right {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 24%;
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: 10px;  
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It kind of depends on what you want to have happen instead.  Scrollbars?  Squish smaller?  One on top and one on the bottom?

Comment: Please be more careful when you submit a question in regards to your grammar and spacing (both grammatically and within your markup/style declarations). :)

Comment: That would be @gilly3, not me.

Comment: either squish it to be smalller or only left div should be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `width` to `21%` for `#left` and then add a `max-width: 340px`.

```
#left {
    left: 3%;   
    position: absolute;
    width: 21%
    max-width: 340px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: i just changed ,but the right div still get pushed to the left and overlap with left div

Answer (score 0):

You can try with set min-width for #left

```
#left {
    left: 3%;   
    position: absolute;
    width: 340px;
    min-width: 21%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#right {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 24%;
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: 10px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#left {
    left: 3%;   
    position: relative;
    width: 340px;
    min-width: 21%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#right {
    position: relative; 
    left: 24%;
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: 10px; 
}
```